# Interaction vertex in non-commutative QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, fourier-transform, interactions, non-commutative-theory

If $\hat{S}_{1}=i \int d^{d} x \mathcal{L}_{I}$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
V\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) & \equiv \int\left[\prod_{j=1}^{n} \frac{d k_{j}}{(2 \pi)^{d}}\right] e^{i k_{\mu}^{j} x_{j}^{\mu}} \exp \left(-\frac{i}{2} \sum_{i<j=1}^{n} k_{\mu}^{i} k_{\nu}^{j} \Theta^{\mu \nu}\right) \\
& \times(2 \pi)^{d} \delta\left(k_{1}+k_{2}+\ldots+k_{n}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
with interaction Lagrangian taken to be
$$
\mathcal{L}_{I}=\frac{g}{4 !} \phi(x) * \phi(x) * \phi(x) * \phi(x)
$$
applying Wick's theorem leads to
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int\left(\prod_{j=1}^{4} d x_{j}\right) e^{i p_{\mu}^{1} x_{1}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{2} x_{2}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{3} x_{3}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{4} x_{4}^{\mu}} \left\langle 0\left|T\left\{\phi(x_{1}) \phi(x_{2}) \phi(x_{3}) \phi(x_{4}) \hat{S}_{1}\right\}\right| 0 \right\rangle \\
=& i \frac{g}{4 !} \tilde{G}\left(p_{1}\right) \tilde{G}\left(p_{2}\right) \tilde{G}\left(p_{3}\right) \tilde{G}\left(p_{4}\right) \\
\times & \int\left(\prod_{j=1}^{4} d x_{j}\right) V\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}\right) \sum_{P} e^{\left(i p_{\mu}^{1} x_{\alpha_{1}}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{2} x_{\alpha_{2}}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{3} x_{\alpha_{3}}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{4} x_{\alpha_{4}}^{\mu}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\sum_P$ extends over all permutations of $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}$ and $\alpha_{4}$.
I understand that from normal ordering we get the four 2-point Green's functions but how does one get the term $\sum_{P} e^{\left(i p_{\mu}^{1} x_{\alpha_{1}}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{2} x_{\alpha_{2}}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{3} x_{\alpha_{3}}^{\mu}+i p_{\mu}^{4} x_{\alpha_{4}}^{\mu}\right)} $?

Comment: It's from https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0301237 eq. (102)

Comment: Looks like they're just Fourier transforming. In case you're asking about the sum over permutations, that just comes from Wick's theorem